# Decimal To Character Conversion On AS/400

Tags: ibm-midrange, control-language

In a CL, I am trying to convert a number (193) to its alpha representation (A).  Coming up with nothing, need a little help.  Is there a CHAR function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example gives the EBCDIC character "A" in variable &TXT1:

```
PGM                                                
DCL        VAR(&NUM) TYPE(*DEC) LEN(3 0) VALUE(193)
DCL        VAR(&TXT2) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(2)           
DCL        VAR(&TXT1) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(1)           

CHGVAR     VAR(%BIN(&TXT2 1 2)) VALUE(&NUM)        
CHGVAR     VAR(&TXT1) VALUE(%SST(&TXT2 2 1))       
SNDUSRMSG  MSG(&TXT1)                              
ENDPGM
```

Comment: All this returns is 00123 instead of "#" (Using your number as an example).

Comment: I misunderstood the question.  Edited the example program to give the EBCDIC character based on a numeric value instead of just converting the number to character.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest in any recent OS release is to redefine, or overlay, the numeric with a character definition:

```
   dcl   &numVal      *uint     2     value( 193 )
   dcl   &charVal     *char     1     stg( *DEFINED ) defvar( &numVal   2 )
```

In a simple CL program, it might look like this:

```
pgm


   dcl   &numVal      *uint     2     value( 193 )
   dcl   &charVal     *char     1     stg( *DEFINED ) defvar( &numVal   2 )

   /* Show current character equivalence... */
   sndusrmsg   msg( &charVal ) msgtype( *INFO )

   /* Set a new numeric value... */
   chgvar      &numVal         ( 194 )

   /* Show new character equivalence... */
   sndusrmsg   msg( &charVal ) msgtype( *INFO )

   return

endpgm
```

The &charVal value will be displayed as "A" the first time and "B" the second. The *UINT variable must be defined as a 2-byte or larger variable since CL can't define integer variables of a single byte. The second byte of a 2-byte integer has the needed bit pattern. The binary integer value has a hexadecimal equivalent in memory that corresponds to character "A", "B" or whatever,

Comment: A nice alternative.  I'm still working on a V5R4 system, so my answer is definitely written from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
CHGVAR   VAR(&CHAR)  VALUE(&NUM)
```

Comment: All this returns is the number left padded with zeros.

Comment: You really need to be careful of what you are doing. Are you calling an RPG program? You can pass everything as *CHAR even if the RPG program takes numerics. The reason for being careful is that literals are passed with default formats